# Pandoc / Latex / Markdown

Tags: pandoc, msword

For a project, I would like to use `.md` files and convert them to a `.docx` file. I would also like to include some `\latex\` commands within the `.md` files. I just do not want to mess up the system that I am currently using because it works well. Which is contradictory, but hopefully it can be done.

**Here is my pandoc setup:**

`pandoc --reference-doc=pandoc/reference.docx frontmatter1.md fm2.md fm3.md fm4.md f5.md ch1.md ch2.md ch3.md bib.md endmatter.md em.md  -o article.docx`

I know latex makes much more sense for what I am trying to do above, but working with `.docx` is a painstaking process. The reference.docx solution works well for me. I just highlight the sections and select the style.

**Finally, my question**. Can I insert `\latex\` commands such as `\newpage` at the end of my `.md` files? So far, I have been unsuccessful.

Here is an example of a `.md` file I would like to get working with latex / pandoc / word:

```
# heading
Some text here.
## subheading
More text here.

\newpage
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I should be posting an answer on my question, but the real answer seems to be that it just doesn't exist. See the following:

**GitHub**
[Pandoc Open Issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1934)

**Pandoc Google Group**
[Technical Discussion about the issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pandoc-discuss/FzLrhk0vVbU/2-nJOAvDJSkJ)

Comment: Converting among differents document formats,  usually is better lost most low level format. For instance, a manual page breaks in LaTeX problebly will end  in the wrong place in another format.

Answer (score 4):

You can perfectly include LaTeX commands in markdown to export with `pandoc` to a LaTeX document, then the LaTeX document can be converted to docx  and *some* of these commands will produce the desired effect in the .docx files, as `\emph{text}`, while others will be ignored, as `\newpage`.

That  is, you cannot export LaTeX commands in .md → .docx conversion as all the latex code will be ignored, but as far as possible you can do it in a .md → . tex. → .docx process like:

```
 $ pandoc -s test.md -o test.tex
 $ pandoc borra.tex -o borra.docx
```

Comment: Thank you @Fran for the idea to export to .tex as an intermediate step. It solved my problems and saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by @hearsay, there is no build-in way of doing this. However, using a few lines of Lua allows to convert all `\newpage` LaTeX snippets into the respective OpenXML structure:

```
-- write to file: docx-pagebreaks.lua
function RawBlock (blk)
  if FORMAT == 'docx' and blk.format == 'latex' and blk.text == '\\newpage' then
    return pandoc.RawBlock(
      'openxml',
      '<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>'
    )
  end
end
```

Run with

```
pandoc --reference-doc=pandoc/reference.docx \
       --lua-filter=docx-pagebreaks.lua
       frontmatter1.md fm*.md ch*.md bib.md endmatter.md em.md \
       -o article.docx
```

There's also a ready-made Lua filter for this purpose: https://github.com/pandoc-ext/pagebreak
See the README in that repo for usage instructions.